# How to use css skew

Tags: html, css

How can I make something like this?

[image]

I am trying to do the same as it is in the picture but it now working.

My html looks like this:

```
<div class="how-we-do">
<div class="left">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia cum necessitatibus eveniet quisquam architecto harum iure aliquid, odit hic quasi assumenda omnis sequi optio nisi sit delectus dicta tenetur officiis?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  </div>
</div>
```

and my css as follows:

```
.left{
  background-color:blue;
  transform: skew(-10deg);
  width: 500px;
}
```

Here my pen: http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/gwNEve
Hope you can help.

Comment: Your skew works, what are you actually asking here?

Comment: The skew works yes. But not exactly as it is the image I posted.
For instance: On the first box,I want the curve to be on the right side only instead of both...and on the second box,it should have only the curve on the left.

Answer (score 0):

To straighten your content, wrap it another `div` element with a positive value. What you see in your image could be done with a background image.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yadwwL

**HTML**

```
<div class="how-we-do">
 <div class="left">
  <div class="inner-left">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia cum necessitatibus eveniet quisquam architecto harum iure aliquid, odit hic quasi assumenda omnis sequi optio nisi sit delectus dicta tenetur officiis?</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="right">
  <div class="inner-right">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia cum necessitatibus eveniet quisquam architecto harum iure aliquid, odit hic quasi assumenda omnis sequi optio nisi sit delectus dicta tenetur officiis?</p>
  </div>
 </div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.how-we-do {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.left, .right {
  float: left;
}

.left{
  width: 50%;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color:blue;
  transform: skew(-10deg);
  width: 500px;
}

.inner-left{ 
  transform: skew(10deg);

}

.right{
  width: 50%;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color:red;
  transform: skew(-10deg);
  width: 500px;
}

.inner-right {     
  transform: skew(10deg);    
 }
```

Comment: If you run my codepen snippet you'll see that it does basically the same with the first container.
But now, the skew on the first box applies to the right and left hand side but I only want on the right as the picture shows.
For the second box..the skew shall apply to the left only.
Hope I could explain properly.

Comment: Check my new changes

Comment: I checked yes.But the shape of the boxes do not look the same as the picture I posted.

Answer (score 0):

CSS skew is not what you want here. You want CSS shapes.
CSS guru Sara Soueidan wrote a [blog post](https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/) about them in depth with plenty of examples. And [Clippy](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) is a great tool for figuring out polygon coordinates.

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #2f73bc;
  font-size: .5em; /*extra small for SO's little preview box*/
}

article {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: right;
}

.gray {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(39% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(39% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    shape-outside: polygon(39% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    background: #d7d7d7;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: right;
    shape-margin: 2%;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 2em;
}

h1 span{
  font-weight: bold;
}

h3 {
    font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

p{font-size: .9em;}

/*buttons*/

article div{position: relative;}
button {
    border: none;
    font-size: 3em;
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    color: #2f73bc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: 5%;
    /* right: 0; */
}
```

```html
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="gray"></div>
  <article><h1><span>WHAT</span> WE DO</h1>
    <div> 
      <h3>Branding</h3>
      <p>Simply scaling or moving elements around on <br> a flexible... READ MORE</p>
    </div> 
    
    <div> 
      <h3>Navigation</h3>
      <p>The site navigation is laid out in <br>different locations... READ MORE</p>
    </div> 
    
    <div> 
      <h3>Content &amp; grids</h3>
      <p>A responsive website will scale headlines, images, <br> text and... READ MORE</p>
    </div> 
    
    <div> 
      <h3>Calls to action</h3>
      <p>Good responsive design considers the  critical calls <br> to action... READ MORE</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</body>
```

And here's a codepen showing it with the buttons: http://codepen.io/StuffieStephie/full/bqodjW/